# Basic Help - Managing Users

Tags: php, html, twitter

I am developing a website based on users dashboard and login and profile. I have an issue with profiles and users.

Can someone explain me how Twitter or even Quora manages to assign every user a special domain like twitter.com/username?

They even do it instantly? I know how to do that like manually, but how do they do it instantly? I know it's a dumb question, but would be glad if you could help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a domain. It's a path on the domain. They rewrite domain.com/stuff to a controller. In php, you may route it to domain.com/profile.php?username=stuff. Then, that page queries the database and populates the view with the necessary information.

```
<?php
// sample profile.php
// NOTE - this is not secure - it's only to provide a general idea
// your code will vary - assuming a mysql connection already exists
// i'm ignoring a lot here - this is just a basic idea

$username = $_GET['username'];
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' LIMIT 1"); // to prevent injection

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
  $profile = $row
}
?>

<html>
  ...

  <span><?php echo $profile['first_name']; ?></span>
  <!--- $profile[column_name] --->
</html>
```

If you are making a site with profiles and pages, you should not be making an individual profile page for every user - use a "template" and then fill in necessary values. If its a custom page, store things like colors and bg images in the database.

It's just one SQL query, so it's pretty fast.

If you are using apache, you can use .htaccess to rewrite the URLs

Comment: I'm using PHP. I really like the idea. Can u give me a link how I can do domain.com/profile.php?username=stuff. Then I'll use the get method right?How do I get the username in the domain?

Comment: see my updated answer. I recommend using a framework like codeigniter to ease in this process

Comment: i got the idea thanks....but why is the above mentioned not secure? Most of my code is in that way?

Comment: hahahahahaha wow. you have a lot of learning to do... As just one of hundreds of examples, what would happen if I make my username index.php? or (another_page_on_your_site).php? or *? or <script>alert(document.cookies.all);</script>

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Apache's mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), what they do is check for the `/<username>` pattern that redirects to a script like `finduser.php?user=<username>`

I think you mean with manually setting the directories, but it's not that way.